# accessing methods of an object within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I have an array which I'm adding objects to dynamically like so

```
var _plugins = [];

this.registerPlugin = function(plugin){

    _plugins.push(plugin);
    plugin.onInit()
},
```

This is all within a class and I am trying to use a method like this which should run the method passed in to `meth`

```
this.runPluginMethod = function(meth, call_obj){
    for (x in _plugins){
        x[meth](call_obj)
    }
}
```

The Objects I am adding to the _plugins array are created like this

```
var ourPlugin = Object.create(babblevoicePlugin);

Object.defineProperty(ourPlugin, 'onInit', {value : function() 
{
    console.log('this is from reflex oninit')

}});
```

When I try running `mianClass.runPluginMethod('onInit', 'a')` It does nothing, doesn't run console.log like it should to my mind.

Can anyone help? am I doing something wrong? is this possible?

Comment: try debugging. what `x[meth]` evaluates to when you run `this.runPluginMethod`?

Comment: I think you are using the for wrong it should be _plugins[x] the javascript foreach like syntax doesnt work as another languages

Comment: What is `this`? What is `mainClass`? How about posting a complete yet minimal working example instead of a bunch of fragments?

Comment: @Carlos487 is correct that I was using the for statement wrong, after changing this then debugging to the statement plugins[x]
Object {}
_plugins[x]['oninit']
undefined
_plugins[x]['onInit']
function () 
{
 console.log('this is from reflex oninit')

}
_plugins[x]['onInit']()
TypeError: Cannot call method 'log' of null

Comment: can you try this (_plugins[x])['onInit'] to see if it's a function the other syntax is for bidimensional arrays

Comment: @Carlos487 it was the same either way if I use (_plugins[x])['onInit'] it gives me `function (){console.log('this is...')}` but if I then try to run that like `(_plugins[x])['onInit']()` it throws `TypeError: Cannot call method 'log' of null`

Comment: Are you running this test in IE because that browser does not have **console** object. Also try debugging the console object maybe it's getting overwritten in another place.

Comment: @Carlos487 I am using chrome, will only be using chrome. I tried this `console.log('a') ; (_plugins[x])['onInit']()
a
TypeError: Cannot call method 'log' of null`

Comment: In the **Console** tab in the developer tools write **console** and hit enter you should get something like this **Console {memory: MemoryInfo, debug: function, error: function, info: function, log: function…}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
this.runPluginMethod = function(meth, call_obj){
    for (x in _plugins){
        x[meth](call_obj)
    }
}
```

You're trying to access a property of a key instead of the object you're looking for.  Changing it to the following should work.

```
this.runPluginMethod = function(meth, call_obj){
    for (x in _plugins){
        _plugins[x][meth](call_obj)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As another example, check the output of the following in a js console:

```
x = ['a','b','c'];
for (i in x){ console.log(i, x[i]) };
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I have changed it to your suggestion and it is better no I am getting `TypeError: Cannot call method 'log' of null` how can it not find the console object?

Comment: Where are you running the code? [Not all browsers have console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log).

Comment: I am running it in Chrome

Comment: Hmmm.  It may have to do with the scope of the function when it is called.  Can you try trading `_plugins[x][meth](call_obj)` for `_plugins[x][meth].call(this, call_obj)` and see what you get?

Comment: I made the change you suggested and made no difference.

Comment: as it is an unrelated issue I'm happy to accept your answer and I'll look into the issue more thoroughly myself. Thank you

Comment: Alright thanks @jbaldwin.  There are a few weird ways your function scope could get mixed up.  Using `call` in this situation (when registering callbacks) is usually helpful so that when you register an event you can register the function and the context in which it is called.  Changing your `registerPlugin` function to allow passing of the context should make it easier to fix.